# How to wait for a state change asynchronously in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to return the state of o from waitState once the state has changed from false to true. I can't see how not to return immediately :

https://jsfiddle.net/msLzovch/1/

```
o = {
    state: false
}

async function waitState() {

  let timerId = setInterval(checkState, 1000);
  
  function checkState() {
      if (o.state == true) {
          clearInterval(timerId);
      }
  }
  
  return o.state; // wrong here
  
}

function theEnd() {
  o.state = true;
}

setTimeout(theEnd, 5000);

async function main() {
  let state = await waitState();
  alert(state);
}

main();
```

Comment: Use an [observable](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable)

Comment: rxjs ? I don't want to use a library for such simple requirement ;)

Comment: Use a promise instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a promise:

```js
o = {
    state: false
}

async function waitState() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let timerId = setInterval(checkState, 1000);
  
    function checkState() {
      if (o.state == true) {
        clearInterval(timerId);
        resolve(o.state);
      }
    }
  });
}

function theEnd() {
  o.state = true;
}

setTimeout(theEnd, 5000);

async function main() {
  let state = await waitState();
  alert(state);
}

main();
```

Comment: Thanks seems to work will study. isn't async supposed to be same as Promise ? If yes why can't I do with async ?

Comment: @user310291 No, it's not the same. `async` allows the usage of `await` and makes the function return a promise that immediately resolves after the return.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work as you expect because there is nothing preventing the funcion `waitState()` from returning a value immediately. `setInterval()` will just return an id that will be stored in `timerId` and `o.state` is accessible.

But you don't need to have a loop reading the variable, you can override the object's [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) method:

```js
const o = {
  state: false
}

Object.defineProperty(o, 'state', {
  set: (value) => {
    this.state = value
    // call your custom function
  }
})

o.state = true // your custom function will be called
```

Comment: Good idea but I don't want to set o state explicitely, I want to be notified by state change coming from some external event (simulated here by timer)

Comment: The function will run every time that property is changed, regardless of how it's changed. The `set` method is the only method that changes the property. This is how reactive fremeworks accomplish this.